# Ajax/Json deja de funcionar cuando incluyo la conexión a mi BBDD

Tags: ajax, json

Archivo: "pruebaJson.php"

```
<?php 
include "includes/header.php"; 
include 'includes/conexion.php';
?>

<!--Éstos dos span muestran los datos que recibo a través de AJAX y JSON.       Éstos datos son la imagen y el ID-->
<span id="respuesta1"></span>
<span id="respuesta2"></span>

<!--slider-->
<!--Aquí estoy mostrando todas las imágenes guardadas en mi BBDD-->
<?php
 $instruccion1="SELECT * FROM producto";
 $consulta1=mysqli_query($conexion, $instruccion1);
 ?>
 <div class="slider-container">
    <div class="slider">
 <?php 
    while($filas1=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta1)){
       echo '<img src="img/'.$filas1['imagen'].'"  onClick="enviarDatos(event)">'; 
    //Cuando hago click sobre cualquiera de las imágenes pongo en marcha la función
   //enviarDatos(). Énvío a su vez la ruta de la imagen sobre la que estoy pulsando
 }
?>
</div>


<script>
    function enviarDatos(event){
        //Recojo la ruta de la imagen
        var imagen=event.target.src;
        //hago un split para sacar el nombre de la imagen de la ruta 
        var imagen = imagen.split("/");
        imagen=imagen[imagen.length-1];

        $.ajax({
            data:{
                imagen:imagen, //envío a través de json el nombre de la imagen al archivo "listar.php", del cuál pretendo recibir el nombre de la imagen (de nuevo, ya que el objetivo es mostrar esta info en una ventana modal) y su ID
            },
            type:"GET",
            datatype:"json",
            url:"listar.php"
        })
        .done(function(datos,textStatus,jqXHR){
                respuesta1.innerHTML="<img src='img/"+datos.imagen+"'>";   //datos que recibo de "listar.php"
                respuesta2.innerHTML="ID:"+datos.id;
        })

    }
</script>


</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Archivo: "listar.php"

```
<?php
//Incluyo la conexion
include 'includes/conexion.php';

if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
 echo "Falló la conexión: %s\n", $conexion->connect_error); 
 exit(); }


//Recojo y guardo el nombre de la imagen que envío a través de AJAX
$imagen=$_GET['imagen'];

//Hago una consulta a mi bbdd para obtener el ID de esa imagen
$instruccion="SELECT * FROM producto WHERE nombre='".$imagen."'";
$consulta=mysqli_query($conexion, $instruccion);
$fila=mysqli_fetch_row($consulta);


//Guardo los datos en el array datosJson, para devolverlos
$datosJson['imagen']=$imagen; //Guardo nombre de la imagen
$datosJson['id']=$fila[0];    //Guardo ID de la imagen obtenido a través de la consulta

header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo  json_encode($datosJson);
exit();
?>
```

Desde "pruebaJson.php" envío a través de Ajax (función enviarDatos(event)) el nombre de la imagen sobre la que estoy pulsando al archivo "listar.php". En listar.php, hago una consulta a mi bbdd para obtener el id de esa imagen y enviar esa información a "pruebaJson.php", dónde muestro el id y la imagen  pulsada en una ventana modal.

Comment: No entiendo por qué incluyes la conexión ahí... ¿no deberías incluirla antes del código que pones al principio del todo, que es donde usas la conexión realmente? También puedes probar si la conexión se está creando bien mediante: `if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
    printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", $conexion->connect_error);
    exit();
}` Esto es sólo para depurar. Si tu código espera una respuesta JSON, lo mejor sería ir controlando el código y al final dar una respuesta en ese formato siempre, sea con los datos erróneos, sea con los datos correctos.

Comment: La conexión va en ambos sitios (son archivos distintos), sólo que en el primer código no la he mostrado.  La conexión se está creando bien, he estado usando ese archivo de conexión (includes/conexion.php) en otros sitios y no me da ningún problema. Así que no sé, es un poco raro. Tienes razón en lo de ir controlando el código, pero no controlo mucho Json y Ajax aún, y la verdad que voy un poco a matacaballo.

Comment: No entiendo entonces cuál es el problema en sí. ¿Te da algún error? ¿Probaste lo que te dije: `if ($conexion->connect_errno) { printf("Falló la conexión: %s\n", $conexion->connect_error); exit(); }`. El hecho de que un código funcione en un sitio no implica que tenga que funcionar en otro. Puede haber un error de ruta en el archivo que incluyes, pueden ocurrir miles de eventualidades que no controlas. Uno de los peores errores en programación es **presuponer** que las cosas van a ir bien. Cuando programas tienes que ser *pesimista*, o sea, pensar que puede salir mal y controlar los errores.

Comment: La ruta es correcta. He probado lo que me dijiste (He editado mi pregunta con el código, imagino que está bien usado) Al añadir ese código para comprobar si la conexión está bien ya hace algo. Pero lo que me devuelve es que imagen e id están indefinidas.

Comment: ¿Dónde te dice que están indefinidas, en PHP o en Javascript?  ¿El archivo donde te dice que son indefinidas cómo se llama,  `listar.php`?

Comment: "listar.php" es el archivo desde dónde espero respuesta, es decir, dónde guardo los datos en el array $datosJson y dónde estoy teniendo los problemas con la conexión. Entonces desde "listar.php" devuelvo lo que hay en $datosJson, que en este caso es id y nombre. Y lo devuelvo a otro archivo (dónde me indica que son undefined). Ese archivo al que lo devuelve es el primer código que puse en mi pregunta. Se deberían de mostrar en : <span id="respuesta1"> y <span id="respuesta2">. Espero haberme explicado con claridad.

Comment: Perdona, pero no, no te entiendo. ¿Tú envías los datos de un archivo PHP a otro archivo PHP?  ¿Cómo los envías?  ¿Por qué los envías? ¿A qué archivo los envías, cómo se llama? ¿Para qué los envías? Sigo sin entender... Identifica por favor en la pregunta, quién es quién... **¿cuál es el archivo `listar.php` y cuáles son los otros archivos**, quizá así nos entendamos?

Comment: He editado toda la pregunta. He puesto el código entero de ambos archivos comentado y explicando el objetivo del código. Espero así se entienda mejor.

Comment: Bueno ahora se entiende mejor y se puede apreciar claramente que tu código no está para nada optimizado: **consulta a la base de datos dos veces para pedir datos que ya han sido consultados**. En la primera consulta tú puedes obtener ya el nombre de la imagen... es  más, lo puedes guardar en la etiqueta `title`  del elemento `src` y obtenerlo en la función `enviarDatos` de JS, mediante algo como `imagen.title`. Haciéndolo así, te evitas un segundo viaje al servidor mediante Ajax, el cual es **totalmente ínutil**, pues ya has consultado los datos de la imagen... no sé si me explico.

Comment: Entiendo, pero el tema es que yo necesito extraer información de la imagen sobre la que he pulsado de mi BBDD. Como por ejemplo el precio o el ID. Al pulsar sobre la imagen puedo extraer el elemento src, pero no se me ocurre dónde o cómo puedo almacenar el id o el precio que obtengo en esa misma consulta para luego poder recogerlos.

Comment: Aún así pienso que no hace falta ir a buscar de nuevo los datos al servidor. Te he escrito una respuesta con más explicaciones de lo que te digo. Analiza si te conviene así. Creo que es mejor aprovechar los datos que traes desde el servidor de una vez por todas, que hacer de nuevo peticiones al servidor. Esas peticiones suelen ser costosas y deberían hacerse en el caso de querer consultar otra tabla o algo así pero nunca para traer datos que puedes tener ya a mano desde una primera consulta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad **no necesitas hacer otra petición al servidor, ni otra consulta a la base de datos**.

¿Por qué no aprovechas la primera consulta y obtienes los datos que necesitas?

O sea, en `pruebaJson.php` tu consulta puede ser así:

```
$instruccion1="SELECT ID, imagen, nombre,  precio FROM producto";
 $consulta1=mysqli_query($conexion, $instruccion1);
 ?>
 <div class="slider-container">
    <div class="slider">
 <?php 
    while($filas1=mysqli_fetch_array($consulta1)){
       $img='<img src="img/'.$filas1['imagen'].'" title="'.$filas1['nombre'].'" id="'.$filas1["ID"].'" data-precio="'.$filas1["precio"].'" onClick="enviarDatos(event)">'; 
       echo $img;
    //Cuando hago click sobre cualquiera de las imágenes pongo en marcha la función
   //enviarDatos(). Énvío a su vez la ruta de la imagen sobre la que estoy pulsando
 }
```

Lo que se ha hecho ha sido agregar información al elemento `img`, siguiendo los mismos estándares de HTML: al elemento `title`, le agregamos el valor de la columna `nombre`; podemos usar el atributo `id` y agregar allí el valor de la columna `ID`, y para el precio, podemos recurrir atributos [`data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). De ese modo, dispones de todo lo que necesitas *in situ*, y te ahorras **otro viaje al servidor**, lo cual tiene su precio, como podrás imaginar.

Luego en Javascript:

```
function enviarDatos(event){
    //Recojo la ruta de la imagen
    var imagen=event.target.src;
    var nombre=this.title; //si no funciona con this, usa la variable imagen creada en la línea anterior: imagen.title;
    var id=this.id;
    /*Para los datos guardados con data hay que usar dataset*/
    var precio=this.dataset.precio;

    /*Probablemente esto no sea necesario*/
    //hago un split para sacar el nombre de la imagen de la ruta 
    //var imagen = imagen.split("/");
    //imagen=imagen[imagen.length-1];

    respuesta2.innerHTML="ID:"+ id+ " precio: "+precio + "nombre: "+nombre;        

}
```

Comment: Ole ahí. Ahí está el tema. ¿Puedes creerte que no tenía ni idea de que podía usar atributos personalizados? ni siquiera sabía de su existencia. Por supuesto que ésta forma es mucho mas óptima, sencilla y hace uso de menos recursos. Muchísimas gracias por tu tiempo y paciencia A.Cedano.

Comment: Me alegro de que te haya servido @Inca. Aún cuando no existan atributos, a veces uno puede recurrir a *trucos* para guardar datos. Por ejemplo, en la etiqueta `name="Titulo_50.20_1"`, puedes guardar tres datos, los cuales puedes recuperar con un `split`. Antes de que HTML fuera mejorado con atributos `data` yo recurría a trucos como esos, para evitar segundos viajes al servidor... parece que los de HTML se dieron cuenta :)... Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: **[¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)** en el Centro de Ayuda.